# Reference to array inside function in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, reference

I am trying to reference to an array inside a function.
Something like this: `a` and `b` are arrays of `Int`s.

```
  var inout refArr = &a
  if(!someFlag) {
     refArr = &b
  }
  refArr[someIndex] = 30
```

This does not compile, can I only use `inout` for function arguments?
If so, how do I do a reference/pointer inside a function?

Comment: What does the rest of your function look like?

Comment: I am changing the values in the array and I need them to be persistence

Comment: The best way is to just use inout parameters in the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` can only be used to pass a variable as an `inout` argument to a function. So the easiest solution is perhaps to use a helper function
inside your function:

```
func foo() {

    func helper(inout array : [Int]) {
        array[2] = 99
    }

    var a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
    var b = [4, 5, 6, 7]
    let someFlag = true

    if someFlag {
        helper(&a)
    } else {
        helper(&b)
    }

    // ...
}
```

You *can* create a reference to the array using `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`:

```
let ref = someFlag ?
    UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &a, count: a.count) :
    UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &b, count: b.count)
ref[2] = 99
```

But there are two problems with this solution:

- `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer()` creates a non-owning reference,
  so the compiler might decide to deallocate the array while the reference
  is still used.
- There is no bounds check on the array.

So to make this work safely, you have to add some code:

```
withExtendedLifetime(a) { () -> Void in
    withExtendedLifetime(b) { () -> Void in
        let ref = someFlag ?
            UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &a, count: a.count) :
            UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &b, count: b.count)
        if ref.count > 2 {
            ref[2] = 99
        }
    }
}
```

which is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inout parameters in your function to accomplish this. Use the `inout` modifier for your parameters and use the ampersand (&) when passing a value into the function like so:

```
func swapTwoInts(inout a: Int, inout b: Int) {
    let temporaryA = a
    a = b
    b = temporaryA
}

var x = 5
var y = 10

swapTwoInts(&x, &y)

x // 10
y // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in swift are not guaranteed to be contiguous in memory the way they are in C, so to insure you have access to a contiguous block, you have to either pass them to a function with an `inout` parameter or--if you really want a reference to an array within the function--create an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` like this[1]:

```
var someFlag: Bool = false
var a = ["a", "b", "c"]
var b = ["d", "e", "f"]

var refArr = a.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (inout output: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<String>) -> UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<String> in

    return output
}

println(refArr[1]) //Will Output 'a'

if !someFlag {
    refArr = b.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (inout output: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<String>) -> UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<String> in

        return output
    }
}

println(refArr[1]) //Will Output 'e'
```

[1. Thread Safety with Swift Arrays](http://blog.human-friendly.com/swift-arrays-are-not-threadsafe)

Comment: `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` creates (as far as I know, not 100% sure), a "non-owning" reference. So the compiler is free to deallocate the arrays a, b while the reference still exists.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases it seems like best practice would incline towards the use of inout parameters and not to mess around with C-style references if you don't have to, but do you have any insight into how to persist `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` references, if as you say, they create an unowned reference