# UnsafeMutablePointer with Struct

Tags: swift, struct, pass-by-reference, swift-playground, unsafemutablepointer

I am not able to use UnsafeMutablePointer to refer to a Struct variable in Swift. Look at this playground example:

```
import Cocoa
var set: Set<Int> = []
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Set<Int>>.allocate(capacity: 1)
pointer.initialize(to: set)
pointer.pointee.insert(1)
Swift.print(set)
```

the output is [] while I expected [1]. What am I missing?

BONUS QUESTION: should I explicitly deinitialize the pointer after the usage?

Comment: `Set` is a *value* type. `set` and `pointer.pointee` are *independent* values. Adding an element to the latter does not change the former.

Comment: how can I refer to set? In C++ it would be simply `Set<Int> * pointer = &set`

Comment: What do you need the reference for? You can "box" a value in a reference  type (class), or pass it as inout argument to functions. More context would b e helpful.

Comment: I have five Set and I have to choose at runtime the set I have to operate with (with a which statement). I can use a nested function with an inout parameter, or a dictionary of Set in order to access the right Set. But I want to do it with UnsafeMutablePointers.

Comment: There is also `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &set) { ... }` which calls the closure with a pointer to the value. But that pointer is *only* valid inside the closure. Generally Swift allows the creation of pointers to values only in a controlled scope which guarantees the lifetime of the pointed-to value.

Comment: Here is a remotely related question for arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796288/reference-to-array-inside-function-in-swift.

Comment: The nested function with an inout parameter is likely the most Swift-like way to do this. There is a reason Swift puts "Unsafe" in those type names; they're discouraged and exist mostly for compatibility with C, not for general use.

Comment: Alternately, if you feel compelled to create a reference type, use `NSMutableSet` (but this is fighting Swift).

Comment: `But I want to do it with UnsafeMutablePointers.` But why?

Comment: @user28434 Because in C the syntax is much shorter, but the use of `UnsafeMutablePointers` rather than `*` discourage me from excessively wanting to use them, so I will opt for nested functions.

Comment: @LucaMarconato, well using `Objective *C*` is also an option for developing for Apple platforms, where you can have all the explosive shortness of C language code working with pointers.